# $ ‎\sigma (‎ T‎ )‎ ‎\subset ‎\{‎ ‎\lambda ‎\in ‎\mathbb{C} : ‎\mid ‎\lambda ‎\mid = 1 \}‎$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

‎If ‎ ‎$ T \in B ( H )  $ ‎is ‎invertible ‎and ‎for ‎all‎ ‎$ n ‎\geq ‎1‎ $‎,‎ ‎$ ‎\parallel 
T‎^{n}  ‎‎‎\parallel ‎‎$‎is ‎bounded, The following statement is
 ‎true?‎ 
‎

**$ ‎\sigma (‎ T‎ )‎ ‎‎\subset ‎\{‎ ‎\lambda ‎\in ‎‎\mathbb{C}
 : ‎‎\mid ‎\lambda ‎\mid = 1 \}‎‎‎‎‎$‎**

(‎‎$‎ ‎‎\sigma (‎ T‎ ) ‎‎$ ‎is ‎spectrum ‎of ‎‎$‎T‎$‎.)

Comment: No, consider for example $T=\frac12\mathbb 1$.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: $\sigma(T) \subseteq \{ \lambda\in\mathbb{C} : |\lambda| \le 1 \}$.

Comment: ‎ how can we prove? $ ‎\sigma (‎ T‎ )‎ ‎‎\subseteq‎ ‎\{‎ ‎\lambda ‎\in ‎‎\mathbb{C}  : ‎‎\parallel ‎\lambda ‎\parallel ‎\leq 1 \}‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎

Comment: It is a different story if $\{\|T^n\|: n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 3):

The above statement is not true. Let $H= \mathbb C^2$ and $T$ given by

$$T(z_1,z_2)=(z_1, \frac{1}{2}z_2).$$

We have $||T^n||=1$ for all $n$ and $\sigma(T)=\{1,\frac{1}{2}\}$.